# JBoss prepared statement too slow

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, jboss

I have a question, would like to get some help with.
I have the query running from Java.

```
SELECT DISTINCT field1, field1
from tblTableA WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE criteriaField='CONSTANT TEXT'
```

I run it with jpa

```
  Query qry = entMgr.createNativeQuery(myQry) ;
  List sqlResult = qry.getResultList() ;
```

Now, that `qry.getResultList()` takes too much time to run - 75 or more seconds.  Yes, it returns close to 700 000 records, but the same query ran on Weblogic 10, using ejb2 runs in less than 5 seconds time

Can anyone help resolving this issue, seems like there maybe a configuration I am missing, or a technique I am not following.

There is something on account of using
`jbosscmp-jdbc.xml`.
I don't have that in my set up, but found out that there is a lazy-loading feature that we can configure.  Now, I am not sure how make the query I am running be configured in xml file.
Also, can this be used with annotations instead of xml file ?

Comment: Try profiling your code to see where the time is spent.

Comment: The time is spent on qry,getResultList() - I have time print out before that and after that.  It is this particular line of code that takes too long to execute

Comment: But is it the query execution, i.e. waiting for database, or the marshalling to Java objects, that's the issue? If it is JBoss, like you presume, then profiling would find where in JBoss code the problem lies, and you can then better see if they know about it already, or report it to be fixed.

Comment: I ran trace in sql, and it shows that query itself runs quick - so SQL Server is not at fault.
So, it must be something that happens in between the select executes and results get propagated.

Comment: Try increasing the -Xms for like -Xms1024m  . If that doesn't work I would blame object marshalling in JPA implementation.

Comment: Is it the only operation in the transactional method?

Comment: Yes, it is the only operation.  I get those 700000 records and place them in the cache.    
I am converting old application from Weblogic to Jboss / from ejb2 to ejb3/jpa etc...

This is the pattern that has been working fast in weblogic version

Comment: What are your JBoss and Hibernate version?

Comment: JBoss 6.1 EAP, but soon will switch to wildfly 8.1
Hibernate I am specified entity manager - version 5.1.0 in the pom.xml file, and it pulled the other hibernate needed libraries transparently at build

Comment: `jbosscmp-jdbc.xml` has nothing to do with JPA FWIW

Comment: What is the type of Object that is in the returned list?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to run this query inside of a non-transactional method:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
List getResults(..){
   Query qry = entMgr.createNativeQuery(myQry) ;
   return qry.getResultList() ;
}
```

This is sometimes not allowed depending on the environment and is mainly used for the optimization of queries expecting to have large results sets and which would later be managed by the PersistenceContext (so basically when you would use HQL instead of native)

But i would give it a try.

Comment: Thank you, Maciej.  I tried it and it did not fix it :(

Answer (score 1):

You are performing this select query within a transaction scope. I found an old [JIRA ticket](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/EJBTHREE-326?_sscc=t) on Jboos's site. As the ticket suggests, there is a potential around the `flush`. If you perform a query with `EJB3`, a `flush` is performed or attempted automatically for all the objects you retrieve with your native query. The idea seems to be avoid getting stale objects from the database. But in your case, it is not applicable. Set the flush mode to `COMMIT`and see if the performance improves.

`query.setFlushMode( FlushModeType.COMMIT );`

Also turn off the Hibernate logging and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried that.
Unfortunately, it did not improve time.

I have switched my method to use pure jdbc - no JPA/Hibernate infrastructure.  Same procedure runs in 4 seconds (compared to 75+ with hibernate)
Unfortunately, having to resort to plain old jdbc, defies the purpose of a project.  So, we have to find a reason why it takes time.